# Como comparar intervalos?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Acredito que não seja difícil fazer isso, mas como não consegui fazer apesar de ter tentado gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar.

Numa planilha de Excel tenho números aleatórios de A1 até A6 e gostaria de comparar as sequencias das duas primeiras células "A1:A2" com "A2:A3", depois com "A3:A4", e assim sucessivamente...a mesma coisa para "A2:A3" com "A3:A4", e depois com todas as outras "duplas de células".

Se os valores e a ordem das "duplas de células" forem iguais gostaria que retornasse "verdadeiro" dizendo quais são os intervalos iguais.

Fiz esta descrição para facilitar e a única restrição na coluna A é que seja entre o intervalo de A1 até A6.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Não ficou claro o que precisa saber das duplas... se estão em ordem? Ou se contém os mesmos valores?

Comment: Acho que dá pra fazer, se você explicar o que perguntei acima. Além disso, existe uma restrição para os números na coluna A? Tipo menores que 100 ou coisa assim?

Comment: espero que consiga ver a imagem

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4373/f%C3%B3rmula-excel-fora-de-escopo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu faria desta forma.

[image: Planilha - Resultado]

Abaixo as fórmulas:

[image: Planilha - Fórmulas]

Primeiro, eu dou um nome para cada par.

Depois, concateno os números (com -- entre eles para não misturar e confundir os números).

Depois, copio o nome de cada par e os números concatenados para uma coluna e uma linha.

Finalmente, dentro da tabela, comparo os valores concatenados.

Edição

---

Não é necessário para a resposta, mas para entender como fiz a tabela, se você quiser replicar. E pode ser um conceito útil.

Para copiar o range como fiz, para as colunas E e F da tabela de comparação:

- Selecione de E4 a F9;
- Digite igual (=);
- Selecione de B3 a C8;
- Pressione control + Shift + Enter. Isso insere uma matriz nas células E4 a F9

Para os valores de G2 a L3:
 - Selecione de G2 a L3;

- Digite `"=transpor("` (sem aspas);
- Selecione de B3 a C8;
- Digite `")"` (Sem aspas) para fechar a fórmula `transpor`;
- Pressione control + Shift + Enter. Isso insere uma matriz nas células G2 a L3, com os valores transpostos (rotacionados) de B3 a C8.

Answer (score 4):

Usando suas especificações o jeito "manual" de fazer o que você quer é:

```
D1 X D2 =$A$1=A2    =$A$2=A3
D1 X D3 =$A$1=A3    =$A$2=A4
D1 X D4 =$A$1=A4    =$A$2=A5
D1 X D5 =$A$1=A5    =$A$2=A6

D2 X D3 =$A$2=A3    =$A$3=A4
D2 X D4 =$A$2=A4    =$A$3=A5
D2 X D5 =$A$2=A5    =$A$3=A6

D3 X D4 =$A$3=A4    =$A$4=A5
D3 X D5 =$A$3=A5    =$A$4=A6

D4 X D5 =$A$4=A5    =$A$5=A6
```

Note que cada linha vai compara os primeiro elemento de Dx com o primeiro elemento de Dy e o segundo elemento de Dx com o segundo elemento de Dy (onde x e y são números de 1 a 6 e y > x) e .

Cada formula dará um retorno FALSO ou VERDADEIRO. Se for preciso, você pode usar a formula `E( )` para comparar os resultados do primeiro e segundo elemento para obter um único booleano para saber se ambos os ranges são iguals.

Outra forma de fazer isso, seria criar um função em VBA.